# Underscore, declares '_' locally, but it is not exported

Tags: angular, service, underscore.js, angular8

Recently I´ve been trying to use the [UNDERSCORE](https://underscorejs.org/) library in an angular 8 application, but I´m getting the warning, *declares '_' locally, but it is not exported* when I try to use it in the recently created  HelperService.

For installation I had tried:
*npm install underscore*
also
*npm install -g typescript@next*
And then
*npm install --save underscore*
*npm install --save @types/underscore*

The warning is showed in the underlined import 
import { _ } from 'underscore';

*import {* _**[JUST RIGHT HERE]** *} *from 'underscore';**

This is the full code of the HelperService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { _ } from 'underscore';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelperService {

  constructor() { }

  public each(array, delegate) {
    return _.each(array, delegate);
  }

  public without(array, delegate) {
    return _.without(array, delegate);
  }
}
```

This service is located in the path:

*Users//workspace//src/services/helper/helper.service.ts

This is the full warning:
Module '"../../../../../../../../Users//workspace//node_modules/@types/underscore"' declares '*' locally, but it is not exported.ts(2459)
index.d.ts(14, 13): '*' is declared here.
index.d.ts(24, 16): and here.

[image: 2]

How can I get recognize the *import { _ } from 'underscore';* correctly?

I´d appreciate any help on this way

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax -

```
import { * as _ } from 'underscore';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `declare module 'underscore';` in your `index.d.ts` file

Comment: Not required as type definition is available for underscore.js https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=underscore

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
import  * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Comment: Please add some detail to your answer to help others understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the braces anymore, it is not an exported member but the default now. You can just import directly:

```
import _ from 'underscore';
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript. TypeScript has its own syntax, function, and variables can have defined types, if you want to use an external library such as `underscore.js` you need to declare type definitions for TypeScript. Some libraries include typing file and you don’t need to install TypeScript’s type destination for them. But in case a library does not have .d.ts file, you need to install it.
**[Type Search](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=underscore)**

**Solution:**

1. Import libraries

   `npm install underscore --save`
   `npm install @types/underscore --save`
2. in tsconfig.app.json, add underscore to array 'types':

   `"types": [ "underscore" ]`
3. usage

   `import * as _ from 'underscore';`